# How to export DokuWiki without machine login

Tags: pdf, export, parsing, dokuwiki

I need a plugin to export the whole DokuWiki, PDF preffered.
I tried bookcreator, dw2pdf and an epub plugin which all do not fit my requirements.
It would be nice if internal links are replaced with clickable document-links...

Thanks & Regards

EDIT:
I have no account for the machine the wiki is running on! Only admin account for the wiki...

Comment: No plugin exists that provides this functionality.  What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: My ultimate goal was, as I said, to export the whole wiki in a document which is human readable and easy to share. I solved the problem with a workaround. I found a plugin which exports dokuwikis to epub files. Then I converted the epub with some effort and manual fixes to a PDF which now looks quite similar to the wiki.

Comment: Just to make sure this is documented - there are several plugins to export to PDF.

Comment: Sounds perfect for the site export plugin. Did you give it a try?